# MySQL: Order by time (MM:SS)?

Tags: mysql, time

I'm currently storing various metadata about videos and one of those bits of data is the length of a video.

So if a video is 10 minutes 35 seconds long, it's saved as "10:35" in the database.

But what I'd like to do is retrieve a listing of videos by length (longest first, shortest last).

The problem I'm having is that if a video is "2:56", it's coming up as longest because the number 2 is more than the number 1 in.

So, how can I order data based on that `length` field so that "10:35" is recognized as being longer than "2:56" (as per my example)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY str_to_date(meta_time,'%l:%i')`

You can find the specific formatters on the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) Website.

For example:

`%k -> Hour (0..23)`

`%l -> Hour (1..12)`

Comment: str_to_date is the way to go, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest choice is to store a integer (seconds) or a float (minutes) instead of a string.  So 10:35 would be 635 in seconds or 10.583 in minutes.  You can sort by these numerically very easily. And you can output them in the format you'd like with some simple math and string functions.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Save it as an integer representing the total number of seconds. `"10:35" => 635`
2. Save it as a timestamp object with no date component. `"10:35" => MAKETIME(0, 10, 34)`
3. Save it with leading decimals or spaces. `"2:25" => " 2:25"`

My preference would be for the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if

<strike>ORDER BY TIME_TO_SEC(timefield)</strike>

would parse it correctly, however it is not an optimal approach to store time as strings in the database, and I suggest that you store them as TIME if you are able to. Then you can use standard formatting functions to present them as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - storing videos length in database.

I solved it by using **TIME** mysql type - it solves all ordering and converting issues.