# MySql PHP sort by personalized time value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, time

I have a personalized time value in my database which looks like this: 3:35 PM (it never begins with zero), I need to order by time asc, I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE(mydate=\"$thedate\") ORDER BY hora+0
```

I get this:

3:35 PM
3:00 PM
3:12 PM

but I was expected:

3:00 PM
3:12 PM
3:35 PM

any help?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is "personalized time value"? What is the type of the field `hora`?

Comment: So what datatype is hora? My guess is a varchar, and your +0 is casting it to a numeric where it will only use the numeric value up to the first non-numeric character, so '3:35 PM' will be treated as 3+0, '3:00 PM' will be treated as 3+0 (so they are all treated identically)

Comment: yes, hora is a varchar

Comment: What I mean by "personalized" is that this is not a time type but a string

Comment: Thank you all, every answer was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like,

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY str_to_date(meta_time,'%l:%i')
```

You can find the specific formatters on the [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) Website.

For example:

```
%k -> Hour (0..23) %l -> Hour (1..12)
```

Source from [MySQL: Order by time (MM:SS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788664/mysql-order-by-time-mmss)

Comment: It is better to keep any data of type TIME in a filed of type TIME. That are the different data formats exist in DB. And then use all the nice date/time functions. Any other solution is tricky and may cause future problems.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY hora+0` is your problem. You're taking your time values, and trying to do an arithmetic addition on them. This destroys the inherent "time" type of the stored time and converts it into a badly mangled integer:

```
mysql> select curtime(), curtime()+0;
+-----------+---------------+
| curtime() | curtime()+0   |
+-----------+---------------+
| 10:16:19  | 101619.000000 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Try just `ORDER BY hora`, **WITHOUT** the addition.

Comment: Yes, but if I order by hora like you say, I get this:

Comment: 10:00 AM 10:30 AM<br>7:00 AM<br>8:30 AM<br>etc.. and I expected 7:00 AM<br>8:30 AM<br>10:00 AM<br>10:30 AM, how do I achieve this?

Comment: what else do you expect when you're sorting strings? `1` is less than `7`. If you want actual time-ordering, then you'll have to use an actual datetime/time field type, in which case `10:00` does come AFTER `7:00`.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I needed: to sort a string like if it was a time type, but now I know how to ask it and achieve it... thank you anyways

Comment: then don't save it as a string. save it as a real mysql time value. Worst case, you can kill performance and dynamically convert to a native time value with `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(...)`.

Comment: Yes that I know, the worst thing to do is to store a date or time as a string, but you have to find a solution to any problem, in my case I am working with a very old database built by someone I never knew and that person decided years ago to do save time as strings, all documentation are now like that if I just change the type, many many mistakes will come to light, so the best solution was to keep working with that database.